# How to calculate % with count base on condition?

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I use crystal report, my report have 2 fields : man=3 and woman=4. I want to calculate % man? with formula field. I try count({person.sex},"man")*100/count({person.sex}) but show Error "A field is required here"? Help me!

Comment: in which section you put this calculation.

Comment: How are you writing count? Your database field format is wrong. What you see when you double click a field from field explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 running total variable, put into the group footer or appropriate section (preferable on any footer- report footer will display total percentage, not group wise) and give condition as you want or check below links.

[Using a Running Total in a Formula in the Details Section of a Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371414/using-a-running-total-in-a-formula-in-the-details-section-of-a-crystal-report)

[How to sum running total field for each group in crystal report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775371/how-to-sum-running-total-field-for-each-group-in-crystal-report)

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/117306-crystal-reports-won-t-summarize-or-running-total-my-formula-field

please check this link

http://crystalreportsblog.com/crystal-reports-running-totals/

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting/Crystal_Reports/Q_28044491.html

Comment: please help me, I can only count how many man? but i can't calculate % man?